# Сформируйте с помощью трех вложенных циклов следующий массив:

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

Нужно сформировать такой массив.

```
[
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ],
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ],
]
```

Вот что получается:

```js
let arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      arr[j] = [];
      arr[j].push(arr[i]);
      arr[j].push(arr[i]);
        for(let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
          arr[i][j]=(k);
        }
      }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогли разобраться.

```
let arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
arr[i] = [];

 for(let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
 arr[i].push([]);

  for(let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
  arr[i][j][k] = k+1;
  }
 }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1490806/edit)».

Answer (score 0):

> Вот что получается

Ты явно перемудрил. А может просто написал абы чего...

```js
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = [];
    for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      arr[i][j][k] = k + 1;
    }
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```